# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) while using a signup firebase method

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

So i'm trying to post using firebase realtime database , my signup function looks like this :

```
  Future<void> signup(String email, String password) async {
    var url = Uri.https(
      'identitytoolkit.googleapis.com',
      '/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]',
    );

    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: json.encode(
        {
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
          'returnSecureToken': true,
        },
      ),
    );
    print(json.decode(response.body));
  }
```

the full error i'm getting is this :

E/flutter ( 7313): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 7313): 
E/flutter ( 7313): ^
E/flutter ( 7313):

it seems like i'm passing through html but it expects json , but the documentation doesn't mention that and also the course i'm following with uses this and it works okay , any idea ?

Comment: is your code null safe?

Comment: not yet no , i don't think so